# Can Data Explorer do those things?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Can Data Explorer do those things? For example:

1. Search all of the questions which have the only tag of the particular tag
2. Search all of the questions which have the particular tag(s) but haven't the particular tag(s)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, see [Recent questions with only one tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/152366/recent-questions-with-only-one-tag)
   . It actually returns all questions with the given tag as the only tag, with most recent first.
2. This is easier to do with the built-in search. Precede the undesired tags with `-`. For example,   you can search for

   [abstract-algebra] [polynomials] -[homework] -[group-theory]

to get all questions questions tagged [abstract-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra) and [polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polynomials) but neither [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) nor [group-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-theory).

Comment: Thank you very much! For http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/152366, I am really very interested to see how does the coding principle so that it can perform by so simple coding.

Comment: @doraemonpaul The short explanation: [SQL is magic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90672/can-we-make-the-title-of-duplicate-questions-say-duplicate#comment480093_164651). Seriously: there are  SQL tutorials online,   one is   [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/), where you can play with simple tables within the tutorial.